# Resharper changing Nuget package DLLs when Visual Studio starts

Tags: visual-studio-2012, resharper, nuget

I'm having an issue with my solution, where opening Visual Studio will cause some of my Nuget package DLLs to be overridden.

I've found this only happens when Resharper is installed. Uninstalling it, or suspending it makes the problem go away.

I'm finding that it's only happening for Nuget packages in my local repository, and the overridden DLLs look incomplete (possibly an older version, but still signed as the latest version). Building the solution then fails. I need to revert the DLLs in source control, then build for it to work.

I've tried finding references to old versions of the Nuget package in my solution, but there aren't any.

Does anyone know how to stop Resharper changing my DLLs when Visual Studio loads?
And, any suggestions about what might be the bigger issue with my Nuget packages?

Answer (score 0):

Issue, seems, that you changed your local copy of DLL from package content in packages folder.
It's bad practice. If you need to modify DLL inside some package - you better to create your own package with necessary DLLs.

Comment: I don't think that's it, because I haven't changed the DLL, and without Resharper the packages are fine. I've even tested by removing the packages directory and reinstalling them from Nuget.

Comment: Then what changed on what with ReSharper?

Comment: So my packages folder is sitting there, with the latest DLLs installed from Nuget. Then I open Visual Studio with Resharper installed, and check those DLLs in the packages folder again, and they've changed.

Comment: I still don't get it - what means "changed".

Comment: I decompile the DLL beforehand using ILSpy, can see 4 classes in a namespace. Then open Visual Studio, and decompile the DLL again to only see 1 class in that same namespace. So it has changed.

Comment: But from where that DLL is getting? What original dll name, version and what is replaced?

Comment: The package comes from my local repository. I've installed this package on another project, and received the correct version (1.0.0.1). On the problematic project, I start with the same DLL (ver 1.0.0.1), and end up with a DLL that is signed as ver 1.0.0.1, but looks more like 1.0.0.0 (from looking at the decompiled code).

Comment: Sean, try to upgrade to NuGet 2.7 and see if it helps.

Comment: I have the same problem. log4net dll seems to be getting replaced by ReSharper. I'm using VS2012 and ReSharper 8. This didn't happen with ReSharper 7. The solution stops compiling. I roll back the dll from source control, it starts working again until a restart of VS. This stops happening when ReSharper is disabled.

Comment: Ege, the same question to you - did you try NuGet 2.7?